# UPDATE cell to be empty MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cell

Looked around on Google and Stack Overflow, maybe I'm just blind though.
Is there a way to UPDATE a table cell with an " " (empty) value. 
Let's say like:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET cellname = ' ' WHERE id = '$idneeded'");
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: yes I do not see any problem in that

Comment: why not try it yourself?

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: also be wary of the difference between an empty string and [NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).

Comment: yes but this returns a 0 in the cell, I want there to be an empty cell.

Comment: maybe the default column value is 0 ?

Comment: your statement will put a space in the cell. try `''` or `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should know that empty string `''` is not same as space string `' '` and not same as NULL value.

to update the cell value to empty string :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET cellname = '' WHERE id = '$idneeded'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET cellname = ' ' WHERE id = '$idneeded'
                            ^^^---not empty. spaces are not "empty".
```

Try

```
cellname=''
```

or

```
cellname=NULL
```

instead.

Comment: `cellname=''` is not same as `cellname=NULL`

Comment: true enough, but OP hasn't said if that field is nullable, so... have to offer both options