# Please check my mySQL query for phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am in need of changing multiple records in my database. I'm new to this so if someone would look at what I have figured out so far through my research and let me know if this looks correct I would appreciate it.

I have few thousand fields that contain "0" and I need to remove every "0" so it to contains nothing. So I ran a query to find them all.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = '_regular_price'
AND `meta_value` = '0'
```

I now need every record or row of "meta_value" that contains "0" to be empty. After looking around I think I can run the following in my phpMyAdmin Query to remove "0" from every "meta_value" that contains "0" and leave all the others alone.

Does the following look correct?

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '' WHERE `meta_value` =0;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The clause is different, so this does _not_ look OK to me. You forgot the clause limiting hits by the `meta_key` in the update query.

Comment: Also there is a difference between `meta_value = '0'` and `meta_value = 0`.

Comment: @arkascha: Doesn't that depend on what type `meta_value` is?

Comment: @RocketHazmat No, `'0'` and `0` _are_ something different, no matter what type that column has. The question if _the outcome_ of using one or another _in some specific query_ changes obviously depends in the type of that column, yes. I mentioned the difference, since I see no sense in using different `WHERE` clauses. If the `SELECT` clause delivery exactly the desired result, then why take any risk and _change_ that clause?

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice its much appreciated!

Comment: Ok I found that the 'meta_value = 0` is longtext not varchar and is not NULL when blank. I don't think I want to run `DELETE FROM` based on what I have read the will remove the row `_regular_price` and I want to put the correct amounts in later.

I want to make the field blank and based off this post here [example post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014836/update-cell-to-be-empty-mysql-php) it should be `SET `meta_value`='' `

Comment: So what I'm looking to do now looks like this 
`UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '' WHERE `meta_key` = '_regular_price' AND `meta_value` = '0';`

Thoughts?

Comment: I was going off this url [sql tutorial link](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqldelete.html) regarding the DELETE FROM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just tried out the following

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '' WHERE `meta_key` = '_regular_price' AND `meta_value` = '0';
```

And it worked!

So using this I was able to update multiple rows of a table in one column to contain a blank value not a NULL value but a blank value. It updated 3562 records and left the other records alone.

Thanks for everyone's advice and tips and help they helped lead me in the right direction.